# how to have one view controller for multiple nib files iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So i've been the whole morning trying to figure out how to load a second nib file from one view controller on orientation change but i didn't succeed and that's why i come here and ask for help. The thing is that i want to load a landscape nib file when the device is rotated. I have this code so far it doesn't work:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [self initWithNibName:@"myNibFile" bundle:nil];
    }
}
```

The new nib is not being loaded. In interface builder i have the file owner being set to this view controller so it should work. I also tried with: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNibFile" owner:self options:nil];`
 but i had no luck either Can you provide an example on how to load a nib file from initWithNibName or a useful link? I don't seem to find it on the web.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even if you do achieve this, your outlets will all be reconnected to the view components in the new nib and so any values you've set (e.g. text fields, button states) in your existing view will be lost once the new nib is loaded.  I suggest understanding the size, positioning and autosizing features of the Size inspector in interface builder - you can achieve quite a lot by setting these up properly to have your view automatically adjust its layout on rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have create new instance of your class.You can not change nib of view controller at run time.

Why are you creating multiple nib files for one view controller. Just create multiple views in single nib file and user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the nib of a controller at runtime is not a good idea at all (not sure if it is even possible *legally*). It can lead to nibs dangling in memory & eventual memory leaks. I encountered the same problem some time back & found that not using IB & nibs is the easiest way to go (luckily my view wasn't very complicated).

The solution was to layout the subcomponents in code & adjust them in accordance with an orientation change. I did the following in my UIViewController subclass-

```
-(void) adjustLayout:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
    {
         mySubview1.frame = frameInAccordanceWithPortrait;
    }
    else
    {
        mySubview1.frame = frameInAccordanceWithPortrait;
     }
}

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self adjustLayout:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```